# VS2019: Extension or default behaviour to link a bookmark to the current git branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

**Environment:** Visual Studio (2019)
**Point of intrest:** Bookmarks (Ctrl + K, Ctrl + K)

I'm looking for either an extension or the setting to link a bookmark (hotkey `Ctrl + K, Ctrl + K`) to the current git branch that is beeing worked on, in order to keep bookmarks branch specific.

For instance: Creating a bookmark while working on branch `Feature1` will cause this bookmark to only exist in the branch `Feature1`. If I checkout the branch `Feature2` the bookmark is removed. Upon switing back to `Feature1` all previous bookmarks are restored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is negative. For the (Ctrl+K,Ctrl+K) [bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/setting-bookmarks-in-code?view=vs-2019), the info of bookmark is not stored in the files which have been included in the several branches. Which makes different branch has the same bookmark.

And It seems no existing setting in vs for this option(Can't meet your needs: different bookmark for different git branch). Sorry for this inconvenience.

And i think your needs is reasonable and this option is meaningful. So I suggest you could report this issue by Help=>Send Feedback=>Post a suggestion about this option if possible. Then please post it here, we who interested in it could vote for it.

And as for extension, not sure if [this one](https://github.com/Konamiman/SuperBookmarks) could help.

[Feature request link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/587517/link-a-bookmark-to-the-current-git-branch-1.html) if you're interested in it.

Comment: Thanks for the extension link @lance.  Here is a link for the `feature request`: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/587517/link-a-bookmark-to-the-current-git-branch-1.html

Comment: Thanks for your help for making vs better. I will vote for it later :)

Comment: You sir, are a great motivator!

Comment: And now we need to be patient waiting for the response from the team!

Comment: I've checked, I think we still wait for further response.The response from produce team, they would consider this suggestion and determine whether to add this new feature:)